# pandas json-normalize syntax issues

Tags: python, json, pandas

#### This is an example of my json payload:

```
{'data': 
  [{
    'predictionValues': 
     [
      {'value': 0.9926338328, 'label': 1.0}, 
      {'value': 0.0073661672, 'label': 0.0}
     ], 
    'predictionThreshold': 0.5, 
    'prediction': 1.0, 
    'rowId': 0, 
    'passthroughValues': 
      {'Id': 'AMF012-000272'}
   }, 
   {
    'predictionValues': 
     [
      {'value': 0.446989075, 'label': 1.0}, 
      {'value': 0.553010925, 'label': 0.0}
     ], 
    'predictionThreshold': 0.5, 
    'prediction': 0.0, 
    'rowId': 1, 
    'passthroughValues': 
     {'Id': 'NSF008-000165'}
  }]
}
```

I am trying to get a df that looks like this and can't seem to figure it out:

```
passthroughValues.Id predictionValues.Value_1.0 predictionValues.Value_0.0  
AMF012-000272        0.9926338328               0.0073661672  
NSF008-000165        0.446989075                0.553010925
```

just running without any perameters doesn't work

```
df = json_normalize(finalPredictions)
```

returns predictionsValues as a series

```
df = json_normalize(finalPredictions, ['data', 'PredictionValues'])
```

that only returns 0 and 1 without the needed Id to associate it back to my data

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
result = json_normalize(finalPredictions['data'], 'predictionValues', [['passthroughValues', 'Id']])
```

I really only care about the positive result

```
result = result[result['label']==1]
```